# excel vba range offset range relative

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to format a region in a worksheet.

I am using the Worksheet_Change so that it always updates on a change.

My goal is to look at all the cells in a region. If the current cell is empty and the cell to the left has numerical value 0, then I want to enter text "N/A" in the current cell.

My attempt is failing as the Offset cannot be used.

```vba
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim updateCells As Range
    Dim myCell As Range

    Set updateCells = Range("B1:M1000")

    For Each myCell In updateCells
        ' NEXT LINE WRONG!!
        If myCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = 0 Then
            myCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: `Offset(-1, 0)`  is looking at the cell above not to the left `Offset(0,-1)`

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for the feedback. I copied it incorrectly. However, even this change is wrong. Is my setup and loop over the range correct?

Answer (score 1):

I would test if any the Target's cells are in the `Range("B1:M1000")`.  You should always turn off events when changing values on the ActiveSheet from the `Worksheet_Change` event.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Target.Cells
        If Not Intersect(r, Range("B1:M1000")) Is Nothing Then
            If r.Value = "" And Not r.Offset(0, -1).Value = "" And r.Offset(0, -1).Value = 0 Then
                r.Value = "N\A"
                r.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
            Else
                r.Interior.ColorIndex = -4142
        End If
    Next

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd go this way

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range, myRng As Range

    On Error GoTo ExitSub  '<--| be sure to exit sub in a managed way and restore events handling
    Set myRng = Intersect(Target, Range("B1:M1000")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) '<--| get blank changed cells belonging to relevant range
    Application.EnableEvents = False '<--| turn rvents handling ofF
    For Each rng In myRng '<--| loop through filtered range only
        If Not rng.Offset(0, -1).Value = "" And rng.Offset(0, -1).Value = 0 Then
            rng.Value = "N\A"
            rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        Else
            rng.Interior.ColorIndex = -4142
        End If
    Next

    ExitSub:
    Application.EnableEvents = True '<--| turn events handling on
End Sub
```

Comment: nice, but I would recommend On Error before .SpecialCells

Comment: @Slai, you are right. That also makes subsequent "IF myRng..." unnecessary. Edited